# How to create custom Patterns that can be applied with Value and Density in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, patterns, texture, halftone

I am looking for a guide or tutorial that will show me how I can create Custom Halftone or Patterns that will change density based the darkness and lightness of an image. I found two tutorials online, but I am unclear about certain steps in the the tutorial.

http://the-print-guide.blogspot.com/2009/06/creating-custom-halftone-dots.html

This tutorial is missing its images.
https://impressionsmagazine.com/screen-printing/graphics-design/creating-unique-halftones/ (see Paragraph 7)

In particular the steps that confuse me is creating the Blend in Adobe Illustrator and what that should look like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *could* save yourself massive amounts of time and merely splurge on the [Phantasm plug in from AstuteGraphics](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/phantasm). It creates custom character halftones right in Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Illustrator part is just to make the element of the pattern a blurred greyscale. Then  Photoshop can use that gray values to vary the size of every element of the pattern.
As the image goes darker the dot becomes bigger.
As the image goes lighter the dot becomes shorter till disappear.

In this link below you can check a similar question using a single image instead.

[similar answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84987/how-to-do-line-optical-illusion-art-effects/120586#120586)

Comment: Thank you for this. This is what I was looking for.